# How do I Find an Escaped Prisoner?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a quest from the 'Companions' to kill an escaped prisoner.
He is said to be roaming Haarfingar.

When I bring up the journal and highlight the quest, It offers no clues on the map.

I have been to Solitude and search a few keeps etc.
Also tried the 'Clairvoyance' abilty.

In all honesty he/she could be anywhere in a large area !!

Anyone have any advice please ?

Comment: You may as well read the answers but just because there's no objective doesn't mean you shouldn't visit the local city's and surrounding wilderness. Good question though

Comment: @Charlo Yes I have tried to find him, but not found anywhere I have looked, but there is a massive area to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With No Quest Marker**

The marker not appearing is a known bug:

> There's a chance that the criminal will have no marker. Sometimes the quest can even move into the completed tab without having finished any of the quest objectives. This makes completing the quest and attempting to receive additional Companion quests impossible even if you happen to find and kill the criminal.

On PC you can get around this through console commands, by accepting and completing one of the other companion radiant quests. The following commands will assign *Animal Extermination* as a new quest and complete it. Afterwards, you can accept new radiant quests from the companion leaders.

> *setstage cr01 10*
>
> *setstage cr01 20*
>
> *setstage cr01 100*

**With Quest Marker**

If a marker does appear on your map then the best way to find him is not to fast travel to his location since he keeps moving. By the time you get there he will be gone. You should fast travel to a location nearby then continue the rest on foot.

You can find more information (*kind of*) at the source [**here**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Escaped_Criminal).

Comment: If your quest is truly messed up as the above indicates it may be, http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Escaped_Criminal shows some console commands you can attempt to use to sort it out either by skipping someone you cant find or resetting the quest. As always, save before you do anything with the console just in case the results are not as expected.

Comment: @James I have already put that information in the answer but yes you're correct, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Was just adding in the option to reset the quest which I did not see in your list, sorry for the duplication of the rest of it!

Comment: @James and Peter. Thank you for your help. I had no idea it was a bug. I will use the console commands to clear the bugged quest. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this quest, and though they told me he was in a particular location, I found that he actually wandered the world a good bit.  I was supposed to find him in a city, but as I was traveling there, I noticed that the map indicator was outside of the city in the fields.  Went there and saw a guy running on the road, and it was him.

I would suggest turning off all other quest indicators except for that one, and you may be able to find him easier.

Comment: I only ever run with one indicator on at any time. Gets confusing with lots going at once lol. I have finished that one you described too. Was a royal pain in the ass. Cheers for taking time to help :)