# Where can I find the escaped bandit?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Duplicate of [How do I Find an Escaped Prisoner?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48158/how-do-i-find-an-escaped-prisoner)

For the Companions, I have a job that is telling me to kill an escaped bandit in Hjaalmarch.  Where can I find him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bandit you're looking for spawns wherever the quest says he escaped from (it could be at any of the Holds, in your case Hjallmarch), but he doesn't sit still. You should have a destination marker on your map pointing to the target, but he moves around. If you try to fast-travel to him, you'll never catch up with him.

You will need to just run along the roads (AFAIK the target sticks to the roads) and chase him down on foot.

Note that this quest has a habit of completing itself; for example, if an animal, vampire, etc. kills your target before you find him, that counts. As long as you're directed back to the Companions you should get your reward anyway.

Comment: It is not giving me a quest marker, but I have been using clairvoyance, and i am now in Whiterun Hold, chasing him down.

Comment: um... Well, I am seriously confused... now it's having me go to the guy who gave me the quest, even though I haven't completed it yet.  I did kill a person marked "criminal" in the town of Morthal earlier, but it did not update the quest.

Comment: that happens sometimes; see my edit